# Time lag between crawling and indexing

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, search-engines

The new version of search console is reporting status 'Crawled currently not indexed' for several URLs. The urls are new and the sitemap was submitted only a couple of days back.

My question is how much delay one can expect between crawling and indexing by Google?

Comment: It isn't a question of lag. Google chooses not to index pages. Almost all sites have pages that are not indexed.

Comment: If that is the case do crawling and indexing happen one after the other instantaneously provided Google has chosen to index?

Comment: Google sometimes indexes new content within seconds of crawling it.   Google really tries hard to do with with important breaking news stories.   It really depends on how important Google thinks the content will be for users and the reputation of your site.  New posts on this site are usually indexed within an hour.     Pages may also get indexed initially but then Google will choose to de-index them later when it determines they aren't very important or that nobody is searching for them.

Comment: Obviously not everyone has a site of StackExchange's authority. So as mine.  In that case shouldn't I expect a reasonable delay in indexing new content after crawling? The duplicate question suggested above tries to answer questions about pages that remain not indexed for very long. Please consider removing the duplicate flag if you agree.

Comment: See also this one which may be a closer duplicate:  [How long for Google to index pages after submit to index? How to check the progress?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/109062/how-long-for-google-to-index-pages-after-submit-to-index-how-to-check-the-progr)